# How to mock AWS DynamoDB service with junit5 and mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I am a beginner in AWS working on a Spring boot application that performs CRUD operations on DynamoDB.
My service uses AWS DynamoDB as a dependency. I want to write unit tests, but I don't know how to mock the DynamoDB service. Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: This [Testcontainers module](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/dynalite/) runs a DynamoDB server on your local machine for testing.